# Sort rows based on two columns

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I have a google sheet that I need the rows sorted based on column 9 then 3, I have ran this script on other sheets with similar parameters and it has worked (both with onEdit and onOpen). I keep getting this error 
Type Error: Cancel read property 'getSheetByName' of null (line 13, file "Code")

Here is the script:

```
SHEET_NAME = "Railcars Archive";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:M";       // I have tried M with and without defined rows
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 9, ascending: true},
{column: 3, ascending: true}
];

function onOpen(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzwjaSNYNzxwE8ac_QhRmi6d7XKev7ISHLg79VLuMz4/edit#gid=1374491574

I can not give edit access and requests for it will not be granted by the owner, but its a rather simple sheet. I do not understand why it would not work on this specific sheet as I've ran this script on a few others without issue. I'd also like to add I do not have a IT / Coding background. Just self-taught to help my company automate schedules and such.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Railcars Archive");
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:M");

function onOpen(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 9, ascending: true}, 
              {column: 3, ascending: true}]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I received the same error, just on line 2 now.

Comment: I made a copy of your sheet and it works well on my side: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSXzK.png make sure you applying it via right project

Comment: So, after a bunch of google searches I will just ask, how do make sure its assigned to the right spreadsheet? I can see in my project view that all of my scripts have the green squares behind the blue arrow, except for this project.

Comment: let me share a sheet with you... authorize the script and see if it works for you - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y1p1VO0aHR_aWkmz4KxRzc5aVEWFtKRhCQKUvwqJ4N0/edit#gid=1374491574

Comment: I went in and selected Tools>Script Editor>Create a new project and it worked. Thank you for your help! I may have some more complicated questions in the near future.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I never replied to your last comment. I was able to vote but it does not display the 1 as I am too new. Thank you very much for your help!